# Cannot see contact in "Add Invitee" on Calendar

Tags: macos, contacts, calendar, google-calendar

I have two CalDAV accounts configured in Calendar. Both are configured in `System Preferences > Internet Accounts` to synchronize both Contacts and Calendars:

[image]

When I go to add a meeting, there's the Add Invitee space as shown:

[image]

I have a contact in my second account, let's call it CalDAV2, that doesn't show up when I start typing his name in the "Add Invitees" area.

How can I remedy my Contacts-to-Calendar interaction here?

Running 10.9.1 on MBA with native apps for each.